# Chain brushes derailleur

Tags: road-bike, derailleur, shimano, shifter

I just got my ever first road bike, Revenio 3.0. I'm so excited. Already got my ever first road bike injury as well - those damn cleats are hard to unclip, springs on those shiny new pedals are too tight.

Anyway, I've noticed that when both rear and front shifters are on their lowest gears (rear - all the way to the right, front - all the way to the left), the chain brushes right side of front derailleur and makes that 'whoosh' sound. That's not right, isn't it? I'm thinking if it's something very easy to adjust, and I can do it myself, or better to take it back to the store?

*Also, can you guys tell me about common problems of bikes of this series or Raleigh road bikes in general that better to know?*

Comment: Firstly: don't use that gear combination. It causes wear on the chain. Second: if you do end up using it adjust your front derailleur so that it doesn't touch. If using index gears, one or two clicks should be enough.

Comment: Many front derailer selectors have some form of "fine adjustment".  On my "brifters" you shift down to the target gear then do a half-click to adjust up.  This is really only necessary if you're "cross chaining", though.

Comment: Don't use big with big and small with small as a rule.

Comment: Also: practice clipping/unclipping while holding to a wall, post or fence until you can do it safely.

Comment: Big with big is a lot less problematic of a combination than small with small though.

Comment: @andy256 really I'm not planning to use that combination, just the fact that it might been improperly adjusted annoys me. Although maybe it's done on purpose as some sort of indication on what shift you are? With these shimano shifters it's no way to know for sure on what gear you at. Probably will take long time of practising to recognise its current position just by the speed of the bike

Comment: Relax. While it *may* be possible to adjust it so that it doesn't happen, and it would be worth doing so that you learn how it works, I suggest just riding it for a while. This is really just a fact of the geometry. The gap in the derailleur needs to be narrow to guide the chain responsively, but that means when you're on the small-small combination, it touches. Let it be for a while.

Comment: BTW, I think my experience with "clipless" pedals was about typical -- two falls in the first two days due to them, then none in the next ten years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derailer  adjustment is easy - at least in theory. When it comes to fine adjustment you may find that you cannot easily get this problem fixed without making something else worse - i.e. its a compromise. Its a good opportunity to learn how to adjust derailers- make adjustments slowly, one step at a time, and count the turns so you can go back to the start if needed.

Given you should not be spending any time in this gear combo, and its not really doing any damage to the bike components, one option is to leave it alone and learn to switch to the smaller chain ring sooner.

It is worth taking it back to the bike shop and seeing if they can tweak it, but do make it clear to them that you do not want to compromise gear shifts to get it fixed.